# How to integrate Spring ,JSF and hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring, jsf

I'm trying to integrate spring with jsf portlet that uses hibernate.I just want to use spring DAO to get the best of spring transaction management.

How could I do this in a simple way?

It's worth to mention that I'm using ant.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring and hibernate are integrated automatically - spring provides enough on that part. Perhaps you can use the `EntityManager` (annotated with `@PersistenceContext`) instead of `HibernateTemplate`.

The JSF integration is done via registering a special ELResolver that resolves managed beans from the spring context.

An example how to do all this can be found [here](http://code.google.com/p/mesir/) - checkout the project and see how it is configured.